# Amazon EC2 instance is not allowing me to login via SSH from my PC

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, debian, login

Remotely, I have been logged in since last night, and it was working fine, just got timeout, now in the morning i am unable to re-login  via SSH to the same Amazon EC2 box, here is my SSH log:

```
sun@From-SSH-Client-Ubuntu-Box:~/To-SSH-RHEL6.4$ ssh -v -i amazon.pem ec2-user@54.22x.x.x
OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-3ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/sun/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 54.22x.x.x [54.22x.x.x] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file amazon.pem type -1
debug1: identity file amazon.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-3ubuntu1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA de:83:e8:bf:51:86:30:89:b9:54:13:52:dc:75:a1:df
debug1: Host '54.22x.x.x' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/sun/.ssh/known_hosts:39
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_1000' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_1000' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_1000' not found

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: my@gmail.com
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Trying private key: amazon.pem
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

Comment: How do you usually authenticate? Username and password, public key file?

Comment: @Mogget: in Amazon EC2 login is mostly with public key (not usually any username/password).

Comment: Do you have another user or method of logging in? If so, I'd recommend looking over your /home/sun/.ssh/known_hosts file and ensuring it's OK.

I also did find a similar error on the [Ubuntu launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssh/+bug/416264) - are you using Ubuntu? The error there related to reverse DNS lookups, however this may be a red herring. But see if you can try connecting from a different ISP/internet connection.

Comment: @AndrewWhite: 1) in that SSH server only username i can login is with `ec2-user` root is disabled and i have no other username left. 2) /home/sun/.ssh/known_hosts is OK, i have deleted the key and retry also to make sure its the right one but no luck 3) Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit using (Ubuntu launchpad no luck) 4) other ISP/network tried + using SSL VPN i logged in to amazon LAN and tried via lan network to access but also no luck. 5) **ALL failed** still having same login failure. Please advise

Comment: That's very strange. All I can think is that the key on the server has been garbled or deleted, or the sshd is looking in the wrong location. Given you don't have access to the server to verify this, I would suggest contacting Amazon support. I don't know exactly the details of what they offer, but I am of the impression they offer "basic" support to all accounts.

Comment: @AndrewWhite: as usual contacting Amazon support is like contacting dead departments. My sever is down and getting reply like this: http://fpaste.org/35383/86519137/